# Using excessive caps in careers listing?

Tags: discussion, jobs

This [listing on Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/31217/are-you-a-damn-good-net-programmer-then-we-want-buildinglink-com?a=ASJEgik) (which has since been removed; [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQrFP.png)) uses a lot of caps in the listing. It also uses not excessive, but moderate swearing. Is this the type of listing that is meant for the site?

Comment: Are you not more concerned it's asking you to email a Gmail address?

Comment: I wish I could downvote the listing.

Comment: Update:  [I actually wish I could downvote the listing.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175224/can-i-upvote-downvote-career-postings)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I read it and it seemed appropriate.  If that attracts the programmers they are looking for from SE, then so be it.  If the community collectively condemns this type of post, then they won't get any applicants and will revise their strategy (or their culture).  Not claiming "free market solves everything," but this is one thing I think can be left up to individual self-interest.

Although as someone who has lived in New York a few years I wonder if they stopped to think about what "ground zero" means.

Comment: Good answer....