# Prevent all caps titles in Careers posts

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs, advertising

Could we implement some rules about all caps titles in Careers posts ? We have [the quality filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127004/230564) to deal with questions/answers in all caps on the main site, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that for Careers.

[image: Screenshot]

This almost looks like spam ads especially in the sidebar like that, I don't think it should be allowed on a quality site like Stack Exchange.

It's similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175219/using-excessive-caps-in-careers-listing), but in that case caps were used to emphasize something, where as here it's just "APPARENTLY CAPS WILL MAKE YOUR JOB LISTING MORE SUCCESSFUL SO WHY NOT USE THEM".

I assume all Careers posts go through manual review before being posted, in that case could the people reviewing them just edit out the caps overdose ?

Comment: > php developer needed > posts ad IN ALL CAPS > mfw

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! While we do keep an eye on listings as they come in, we do not review all of them (that would require a lot of manpower). We rely in part on the community to let us know when something isn't as should be, and will take action accordingly. In this case, I went in and edited the title, and we will let the company know to please not use all caps.

As for your feature request, I will pass it along. I like it, but we have many other things we're working on at the moment so marking as deferred for now.

Comment: @AndréDaniel If you go to the listings, there's a link to flag it.

Comment: @Juice nevermind, I just wasn't logged in.